How can i solve this type of exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\subug\OneDrive\Desktop\React CLI Project\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-00f145fb-33a6-47aa-96fd-300b0f75f2e0) to immutable location (C:\Users\subug\OneDrive\Desktop\React CLI Project\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\subug\OneDrive\Desktop\React CLI Project\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-00f145fb-33a6-47aa-96fd-300b0f75f2e0) to immutable location (C:\Users\subug\OneDrive\Desktop\React CLI Project\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)

How to solve this exception.Give me an solution.

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78481606/6083675

This could be because the project is nested within a OneDrive folder.  Try moving the project to a folder that is not setup to sync/watch from OneDrive and attempt your build again.
The OneDrive folder is not "immutable" (meaning not changed by outside apps) since OneDrive may sync/change the files based off of cloud changes, which may be in conflict with your build process.
It is recommended that instead of using OneDrive as a "backup" for your project, to instead use git/GitHub or something similar as a code repository/backup for your files.

Thank you for your Solution.Currently this is working properly.

If this solution worked for you, would you mark it as the best answer so future users can know what the resolution is?

go to android folder and clean your gradle.
cd android
./gradlew clean

then run the server with clear cache flag.
npm start -- --clear-cache

if that still doesn't work, try to update your sdk from Android Studio.

i solve this way

Delete ".gradle" in android
npm install
npm run android

