React Native build failure: java.io.UncheckedIOException while running npx react-native run-android
I encountered an issue while trying to run my React Native application on Android using the command npx react-native run-android. The build process fails with the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewApp\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-b6ab17a5-c09d-436d-af19-0615c1f14709) to immutable location (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewApp\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewApp\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-b6ab17a5-c09d-436d-af19-0615c1f14709) to immutable location (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewApp\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at Gradle Help.


You can either downgrade to gradle 8.5 or upgrade to Gradle 8.7+, See Details in: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/27844
